# Advanced Custom Fields, двойное сохранение поля

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, почему поле из плагина acf сохраняется дважды?
Подозреваю, что срабатывает стандартный хук save_post и хук acf/save_post одновременно.
Нужно сделать, чтобы при сохранении нового поста обновлялось acf-поле этого поста только один раз. Использую такой код:

```
add_action('save_post', 'add_slug', 10, 3);

function add_slug($id, $post, $update) {
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $id ) || get_post($id)->post_status != 'publish' )
        return;
    if ($post->post_type == 'custom_type') {
        $field = get_field('acf-link-test', $id);
        if (empty($field)) {
            $field = 'http://link_to_partner=';
        }
        $name = $post->post_name;
        $link = $field . $name;
        update_field('acf-link-test', $link, $id);
    }
}
```

Как это предотвратить, чтобы дважды не сохранялось?

Comment: кто-то подскажет?

Comment: есть идеи как это исправить?

Comment: уже решил проблему, нужно было вызывать update_post_meta